# How to use isomorphic-fetch in typescript

Tags: javascript, isomorphic-javascript

I am getting error @types/isomorphic-fetch has no default export fetch

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export const AUTH_FAIL = "AUTH_FAIL"
export const ERROR_FETCH = "EROR_FETCH";
export const SUCCESS_FETCH = "SUCESS_FETCH";
export const START_FETCH = "START_FETCH";

export function start_fetch(){ 
    return function(dispatch: any){
        return fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/data")
        .then(
            response => response.json()
        )
    }
}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try to install it using npm ? npm install @types/isomorphic-fetch
and import fetch like below:
import * as fecth from 'isomorphic-fetch";

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make it work by importing the library like this:

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
```

I had to polyfill ES6 Promises before that though.  For example:

```
import * as e6p from "es6-promise";
(e6p as any).polyfill();
```

Comment: This resolved my issue. I put it in a new setupFile with just the `import 'isomorphic-fetch';`